# Blow-Up of Quasiprojective Variety and Conormal Space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup, tangent-bundle

My question is with regards to understanding blowing up a variety, $X$, along an arbitrary subvariety, $Y$, with respect to the conormal bundle. I have been told that a blow up in essence is replacing the subvariety $Y$  by the projectivized conormal space for each point in $Y$. My understanding of the conormal space is to be the dual of the normal space at that point, which is defined by $N_p = T_p(X)/ T_p(Y)$, with $T_p(X)$ the affine tangent space. So, the fibers $\pi^{-1}(p)$ for a point $p \in Y$ will be isomorphic to $(N_p)^*$.

Please let me know if my understanding of this is even correct and perhaps explain this through simple examples of blow ups like blowing up a point in projective space, or blowing up the cuspidal cubic or the nodal cubic as I am most familiar with these examples.

I noticed on many posts here that Eisenbud and Harris' Geometry of Schemes book is highly recommended for understanding blow ups, but I would prefer to understand this without the language of schemes or sheaves (just language of quasiprojective varieties and vector bundles). Thank you for any help you are able to provide!

EDIT: I am currently learning from Shafarevich's Basic Algebraic Geometry textbook (3rd ed) which deals with blowing up at a point in projective space or a quasiprojective variety (Chapter 2 Section 4)
i.e. $\sigma: \Pi \to \mathbb{P}^n$ where $\Pi \subset \mathbb{P}^n \times \mathbb{P}^{n-1} = \{ ([x_0: \cdots : x_n] , [y_1 : \cdots : y_n] ) \}$ defined by $x_iy_j = x_jy_i$ for $1 \leq i,j \leq n$. with center $\xi = [1 : 0 : \cdots : 0]$

Comment: You mention that you're familiar with some examples of blowups - what definition of blowups do you have?

Comment: The definition that I am using comes from Shafarevich's Basic Algebraic Geometry

Comment: Adding this definition in your post with an [edit] will improve your post and make it more likely that you will get help - not everyone has a copy of that book with them, and even those who do may not want to go find it in their library and track down the definition.

Comment: You gave the definition of blow-up at a point, but not along a subvariety.

Comment: The definition of a blow-up along a subvariety is not contained in this section of Shafarevich, which is why I am attempting to understand blow ups in terms of the conormal space and hoping to generalize from the case of blowing up a point to blowing up along a subvariety in terms of this new construction